# Way to find a td inside of a tr. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I am working for a update on a chrome extension for a page where I have the following table.

```
<tr class="MessageContent">
  <td colspan=3>
    data
  </td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to change the second tables color.

I have access to the first table, but need to somehow select the second table.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("MessageContent")[0]; // First table
```

Nothinng I have tried has worked.

Comment: That's invalid HTML. A `<tr>`'s children should only be `<td>`s. Fix that first

Comment: oops yeah thats a td, sorry

Comment: don't just type tags and go "GOOD ENOUGH!", read the tag's description: _what on earth_ does this question have to do with the unix `tr` command line utility? Welcome to Stackoverflow but read up on the site you're posting to, this is not how you post [a good question](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: And as a secondary comment: your code is not a table. It's a row in a table,  and your question is about two tables so: where's the rest of the [mcve] code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `querySelector` instead, to select the first `<td>` inside a `<tr class="MessageContent">`:

```js
document.querySelector('tr.MessageContent > td').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="MessageContent">
    <td colspan=3>

      data

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you need to be more specific and are sure the td always has `colspan=3`, then

```
document.querySelector('tr.MessageContent > td[colspan="3"]');
```